# Proving Applications of the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The first application of the IVT I'm trying to prove:

$1$. Let the function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be continuous. Then $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(c)=c$.

I tried to prove by first saying that $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(c)=h \in [a,b]$. Then I said for $h \in [a,b]$ $\exists g \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(h)=g \in [a,b]$. I then had to show $f(c)=g$ but I couldn't think of how I could do this.

The second application:

$2$. Assume $f,g: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are continuous and let $f(a)<g(a)$ and $f(b)>g(b)$ then $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(c)=g(c)$.

To prove this I said $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f(c)=h \in [a,b]$ and $\exists d \in [a,b]$ s.t. $g(d)=h \in [a,b]$ but I then couldn't think of how to prove that $f(c)=g(d)$.

I'm also not sure if my approach to either of these problems is correct in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, try examining the continuous function 
$$
g(x)=f(x)-x
$$
and show it has a zero, by the intermediate value theorem.

You can prove the second by examining $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ and by a similar argument, you can concluding using the IVT there is a zero of the function for some $x\in (a,b)$.